# VOLTTRON Agents Naming

Tags: volttron

When I install my agents in VOLTTRON platform, all of them are assigned the same name "Agentagent-3.0", I can change part of its name in setup.py. But, I don't know the right way to give a name to agents.  Where should I set agents name?

Answer (score 3):

One way to refer to each agent would be: I can use the tag command to distinguish between agents: volttron-ctl tag myTag agentUUID. Then I can refer to agents by their tag such as: volttron-ctl stop –tag myTag.

Comment: Using the tag is what I usually do.

Comment: Yes using tags would be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that I missed this question when it first came up Amin.

You need to change the Agent's VIP IDENTITY. There are several ways to do this based on your circumstances.

If you are the agent developer you can create a file called IDENTITY that contains only the desired identity in plain text. You can see an example of this in services/core/MasterDriverAgent in the VOLTTRON repository.

If you are deploying an agent and want to specify a different VIP IDENTITY you can specify the environment variable AGENT_VIP_IDENTITY in your make script. You can see a commented out example of this in scripts/core/make-listener. This method overrides the preferred identity of the agent, if any.